# Taking resveratrol and NMN supplements

Tags: supplement

David Sinclair (Harvard Medical School) has said to take NMN and resveratrol supplements to fight ageing and degenerative diseases.

[image: tweet]

Example of same supplements taken: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yWx77ARQ9lo

Are there any scientific studies about the effects of them for a healthy person at different ages?

Comment: Welcome to Medical Sciences! Please take the [tour] and read the [help]. For [reasons mentioned in this post](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/q/411) and in [ask], we require some degree of prior research when asking questions. *See [this list of helpful resources](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/a/784)*. Please help us to help you and [edit] your question to provide more information on what you have read on this subject, what made you ask this question, and any problems you are having understanding your research. If you found nothing, what did you Google?

Comment: And please add a link to where he said this along with a relevant quote.

Comment: Well I found nothing on Google scholar, I don't really think I can say anything else

Comment: I'm not surprised you found nothing. They're supplements, and supplement manufacturers have almost no incentive to do clinical trials with their own products. There seems to be some basic research using animal models, but that's not going to answer your question about people.

Comment: @CareyGregory wrote: "supplement manufacturers have almost no incentive to do clinical trials with their own products".  This statement is a common fallacy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Are there any scientific studies about the effects of them for a healthy person at different ages?

Regarding NMN: study {1} shows it is safe to use on humans, but no study yet on the efficiency in terms of lifespan increase. Studies on NMN have been on other animals. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nicotinamide_mononucleotide for some references.

Regarding the efficiency of resveratrol in terms of lifespan increase, see https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Resveratrol&oldid=981556075#Lifespan:

> There is insufficient evidence to indicate that consuming resveratrol has an effect on human lifespan.

FYI:  [Is there any downside in combining the ingestion of NR and NMN supplements to increase one's level of NAD+?](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/q/18931/43)

---

References:

- {1} ["Effect of oral administration of nicotinamide mononucleotide on clinical parameters and nicotinamide metabolite levels in healthy Japanese men"](https://www.jstage.jst.go.jp/article/endocrj/advpub/0/advpub_EJ19-0313/_pdf/-char/en). *Endocrine Journal*. November 2019.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, if I sum up, the effectiveness is only partially proven but there is no known risk?

Comment: @Blincer correct, I'm taking resveratrol + NR myself. I do believe to have seen a study mentioning some potential bad effect of NMN but could be mistakenly and the results would need to be confirmed be other studies anyway. I'll let you know if I find the study. Most likely all those complements aren't life changing unfortunately unless you're a mouse, but hopefully I'm wrong. NR and NMN are on the expensive side for a complement.

Comment: Thank you again, this is very interesting